# XSS prevention - jqencoder - canonicalize more than once?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, xss

I'm using a jQuery plugin to prevent XSS attacks. Its called jQuery-encoder

https://github.com/chrisisbeef/jquery-encoder

There are a series of functions with canonicalize - ation used multiple times.

is it safe to canonicalize data more than once? I read somewhere on OWASP that this was not preferred and can lead to risks.

Thanks, much appreciated!

-dkavathe